# how to use ListView to display INI-files content

Tags: asp.net

is there any example code  for editing INI file(s) with aspx listview interface, code should read the INI file and display selected INI values on screen.

I have a simple INI File  (key=value)  that describes the user-interface like this:

```
> Setting=inikey
> Name=inival 
> Description=show me on GUI
> Type=combo
> Values="25","35","45"
```

I need to draw this interface to browser.

Comment: yeah.. these are still used even in Windows ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds easy enough, and INI files are in a fairly trivial format. If you have a specific question, feel free to ask it ...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say open the ini file, traverse the lines, split each on the '=' and you have parsed your ini file... Then just create either an anonymous type, or, if it's aways the same format, create a class and set the values...